# How to map Ctrl+Insert to Copy in Konsole at fedora 22?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cut-and-paste, fedora-22

**original header:**

> How to map Ctrl+Insert to Copy at fedora 22?

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I've recently upgraded from Fedora 20 to Fedora 22. 
(using fedup)
after the upgrade `Ctrl+Insert` no longer function as Copy 
(as in Copy&Paste)

Instead it prints "5~"

how can i restore it's functionality ?

Thanks

Comment: In what environment?

Comment: Gnome 3.16 (the default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, and it basically is that I was asking the wrong question. 
`Ctrl+Insert` works pretty much everywhere except inside Konsole (`konsole5.x86_64`).

and it can be easily fixed by mapping it as an alternative shortcut
Settings -> Configure Shortcuts -> define Alternative for 'Copy'